# Turn my 3 legged APS hubs viewer into a 2 legged one

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I've created a viewer for my ACC that uses 3 legged authentication, but I want to convert it to 2 legged authentication. I tried the same steps that we use in the simple viewer, but I couldn't. Is there a sample of using x-user-id to access hubs?

Due to the fact that I didn't use the "x-user-id" to make my viewer use 2-legged authentication.